# How to make php pages load faster when fetching bulk of information?

Tags: php, domparser

Basically I am building a website that does web scraping and fetches particular web pages from around 8 different websites to extract price. I am using  `file_get_html()` function of `PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser` extensively to fetch the page source into a string variable and extract the price information out of that.

Now the main problem is the page which shows the price information from all different sites is taking very long time to load.

So my question is

1. How to make the page load faster. &
2. How to load the page in steps so that those information which has been fetched loads and other information will load subsequently like google image search.

Comment: you really should store the prices and all the information somewhere (I would use a database) to avoid fetching all the time the same web pages. The information doesn't change 1000 times a day?

Answer (score 5):

Don't fetch the data on page load, but do it in a background job (cronjob?) and save it in the database.

So you will only have to retrieve the data from the database. Additionally you could add a text with a timestamp when the data has been retrieved and / or give the user the ability to manually update (get) the data.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of you can use cURL instead of `file_get_html()`, It's easy and very configurable + it's faster than using the simple html dom function. Obviously you will have to convert the string into a dom object using the simple html dom function `str_get_html()` after that.

Comment: What does cURL has to do with a DOM parser?

Comment: He is fetching data from a website before parsing using the file_get_html function which makes us of the file_get_contents and that function is slow.